# Why am I getting very little variance in predict_proba values in XGBoost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost

I'm having trouble understanding why all the values when calling the `predict_proba` function in the xgboost library in python are in a quite close range of values, even though the model AUC in the test set is good enough for the problem at hand (0.78).

[image]

As you can see, the variance is low and the results are quite near around the 50% mark.

The test size is approximately a 15% of the available data (5000 observations).

I'm using the following parameters:

```
{'colsample_bytree': 0.5, 'gamma': 2, 'learning_rate': 0.01, 'max_depth': 8, 'min_child_weight': 10,
                'n_estimators': 10, 'scale_pos_weight': 7}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Without access to the data you are working with, it is impossible to say why exactly you are seeing what you are seeing

Answer (score 1):

Without access to the data you are working with, it is impossible to say why exactly you are seeing what you are seeing.

That said, however -

- The simplest solution is to validate against an "Out-of-time" dataset
- Check for the variance / cardinality of your input features. If, for example, you have 2 independent binary variables, then you only have 4 possible combinations for both of them. No matter how large your training dataset - your `predict_proba` will only give 4 values.

Comment: I have checked with an Out-of-time dataset and the results are the same.

Comment: Besides that, I have 10 features containing both numeric and categorical values, converted with a catboost_encoder, I've checked and the cardinality is the usual.